# firebase.messaging is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using code from Firebase's FriendlyChat codelab to implement a chat feature in my web app. I would like to send push notifications, which Firebase explains is possible. However, I keep getting "firebase.messaging is not a function" and I'm completely lost as to what it means.

Has anyone run into this? Has anyone found a solution?

Script in my html to initialize firebase:

```
  var config = {
    apiKey:\\,
    authDomain: \\,
    databaseURL: \\,
    storageBucket: \\,
    messagingSenderId: \\
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  this.auth = firebase.auth();
  this.database = firebase.database();
  this.storage = firebase.storage();
  this.messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Messenger.js:

```
// Saves the messaging device token to the datastore.
FriendlyChat.prototype.saveMessagingDeviceToken = function() {
  firebase.messaging().getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log('Got FCM device token:', currentToken);
      // Saving the Device Token to the datastore.
      firebase.database().ref('/fcmTokens').child(currentToken)
          .set(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    } else {
      // Need to request permissions to show notifications.
      this.requestNotificationsPermissions();
    }
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(error){
    console.error('Unable to get messaging token.', error);
  });
};

// Requests permissions to show notifications.
FriendlyChat.prototype.requestNotificationsPermissions = function() {
  console.log('Requesting notifications permission...');
  firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(function() {
    // Notification permission granted.
    this.saveMessagingDeviceToken();
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', error);
  });
};
```

Comment: It seems like you're not including the Firebase messaging SDK: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>`

Comment: Please note this issue stems from a tutorial that asks the student to run Firebase 3.8, which may be what's confusing. Here is a link to the step in the tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#9